# Calling function by other function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make Rock Paper Scissors match of computer versus human player. I have function `computerplay();` that generates random value out of three possible strings ( "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors") as a computer selection of value for the game match. Using third function `save();` I allow player to input his selection into HTML form and try saving it into round(); function.

As an outcome I want to get variables c or p incremented or string "draw" printed as an indication that `round();` gets both computer selection which is stored in x and the player selection which is variable player. It seems that both x and player gets their values attached but `round();` function does not receive it. Thank you for helping to solve it.

```js
function computerPlay() {
       const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        if (number % 3 === 0) {
                return 'Rock';
       }
        if (number % 3 === 1) {
                return 'Paper';
        }
        return 'Scissors';
}


var p = 0;
var c = 0;


 var x = computerPlay();
    var player;
      player = document.getElementById("player").value;
 document.write(x);
function round ( playerSelection = player, computerSelection =  x ) {

 document.write(player);
 document.write(x);
 
                 if (playerSelection == 'Rock' && computerSelection == 'Rock') {
           
                      
                      
                     document.write (p);
                     document.write (c); 
                    
                     document.write("draw"); 
                  }

                 else if (playerSelection == 'Rock' && computerSelection == 'Paper') {
           
                      
                     c++; 
                     document.write (p); 
                     document.write (c); 
                     document.write("comp"); 
                  }
           
                 else if (playerSelection == 'Rock' && computerSelection == 'Scissors') {
           
                      
                     p++;
                     document.write (p);  
                     document.write (c); 
                     document.write("player"); 
                  }
                 else if (playerSelection == 'Scissors' && computerSelection == 'Rock') {
           
                      
                     c++;
                     document.write (p);  
                     document.write (c); 
                     document.write("comp"); 
                  }
                else if (playerSelection == 'Scissors' && computerSelection == 'Paper') {
           
                      
                     p++; 
                     document.write (p);
                     document.write (c); 
                     document.write("player"); 
                  }

                else if (playerSelection == 'Scissors' && computerSelection == 'Scissors') {
           
                      
                     document.write (p);
                     document.write (c); 
                     document.write("draw"); 
                  }

                 else if (playerSelection == 'Paper' && computerSelection == 'Rock') {
           
                      
                     p++; 
                     document.write (p);
                     document.write (c); 
                     document.write("player"); 
                  }

                else if (playerSelection == 'Paper' && computerSelection == 'Scissors') {
           
                      
                     c++; 
                     document.write (p);
                     document.write (c); 
                     document.write("computer"); 
                  }

                 else if (playerSelection == 'Paper' && computerSelection == 'Paper') {
           
                      
                     document.write (p);
                     document.write (c); 
                     document.write("draw"); 
                  }
              }









  function save() {
      var player;
      player = document.getElementById("player").value;
       document.write (player);
       document.write(x);
       computerPlay();
       var x = computerPlay();
       round();
       

     

}



document.write (p); 
    document.write (c); 

if ( c == 5 ) {
    document.write (c); 
    document.write ('computer win');
}
else if ( p == 5 ) {
   document.write ('player win');
 }
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<form id="form">
  <input id="player" type="text" min="1" name="player">
  <button type="button" onclick="save();">Get Value</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi ok so i think i see the problem here, you are setting default values to playerSelection and computerSelection but these values are set on load and at that time player selection would be empty. 
you need to pass the player in round() in save() , this could solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you are using two variables both called `player`, one here:

```
var x = computerPlay();
  var player; 
    player = document.getElementById("player").value;
```

and one here:

```
function save() {
  var player;
  player = document.getElementById("player").value;
```

The first variable is declared in the main body of the script, which means it has a 'global scope'. The one you are defining inside `save()`, instead, has a 'function scope' (meaning it will not be visible to anyone outside the body of that same function).

Since you are calling `round()` without parameters, it will initialize them with their default values, taking those values from the scope in which the function declaration takes place (in this case, the global scope). Since the global `player` is initially empty and you never change that variable, round will always have its first parameter as an empty string.
There are a number of ways to "fix" this:

- Get the variable directly inside `round()`:

  ```
    function round(/* ... */) {
        player = document.get...
  ```
- Actually pass the parameter to the function:

  ```
    round(player);
  ```
- Update the value of the player variable instead of creating a new one:

  ```
    var player;

    function save() {
        player = document.get...
        round();
    }
  ```

For more information on JavaScript scoping rules, read [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)